# AngularJS - ng-repeat default value for select option

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form where a user needs to select the type of shifts for two weeks. What I need to do is to set **UNIQUE** default values for each cell, e.g. `Day 1: D, Day2:N, etc.`. How can I achieve this?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fujik8467/axnm0cy9/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
 <select ng-model="day.selectedShiftType" ng-options="shift as shift.strId for shift in shifts" ng-init="day.selectedShiftType = shifts[0]">
```

The above will always select first option but we can make this random using this code:
`$scope.GetRandomIndex = function() { 
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1); 
}`

html code:

```
<select ng-model="day.selectedShiftType" ng-options="shift as shift.strId for shift in shifts" ng-init="day.selectedShiftType = shifts[GetRandomIndex()]">
```

Comment: The above will always select first option but we can make this random using this code:`$scope.GetRandomIndex = function(){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
},` and html code: `<select ng-model="day.selectedShiftType" ng-options="shift as shift.strId for shift in shifts" ng-init="day.selectedShiftType = shifts[GetRandomIndex()]">`

Comment: What if I want to purposely set specific options from my controller.js? For example, I have a set of existing selections (Day1, 'D'...) and I want to load them as a default value?

Comment: You can modify the method by sending day number as an argument and add if conditions accordingly. Do you have any order or do you want random selection?

Comment: I was early on that reply, let me go check it out.

Comment: console.log reveals what I need and the positions that I need to settle with, but it still doesn't select the default item that I specified

Comment: The jsifiddle works fine, just that it's not really working on my end inside my IDE.

Comment: Does your problem still exist?

Comment: Yea, for some reason. I'm still trying to solve it atm

Comment: Was it fixed or still have issues?

Comment: It seems to not want to listen to us, so we took another approach instead, which was to just display the default selections, and allow the user to pick a new set of selections.